# Supervisord on Fedora configuration error

Tags: fedora, supervisord

I am trying to install supervisor on my Fedora 17, using this link as reference:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

It works fine except one trivial problem (I believe).

> A simple configuration for our script, saved at /etc/supervisor/conf.d/long_script.conf, would look like so (...)

My problem is, that I have only files/directories:

```
/etc/supervisord/
/etc/supervisord.conf
```

I have tried to create conf.d directory under /etc/supervisord/. I have put my config file into /etc/supervisord/conf.d/ and /etc/supervisord/ and also /etc/sueprvisor/.

Despite my effort when issuing command:

```
supervisortctl reread
```

I receive:

```
No config updates to processes
```

Anyone has a clue what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

(I'm on Fedora 20) If you look at `/etc/supervisord.conf` at the bottom you see

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.ini
```

So on Fedora your configuration files should end in `.ini` instead of `.conf`. I had this same problem and running `supervisorctl reread` after this detects stuff

Comment: I installed supervidord in centOS and it has `.ini` instead of `.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a folder specifically for your configuration file, you can specify its path with the `-c /path/to/your/file` or `--configuration=/path/to/your/file` option.

Source: http://supervisord.org/running.html